# Expectation of share of Geometric Brownian motions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Fix $N\in\mathbb{N}$. For any $i\in\{1,...,N\}$,
\begin{equation}
X^i_t=x_i\exp\left(\sigma B_t^i\right)
\end{equation}
where $B^i$ are independent standard Brownian motions, and $x_i>0$.

Question:Let $r_i(x)=\frac{x_i}{\sum_{k=1}^Nx_k}$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}_+^N$, then what is $\mathbb{E}[r_i(X_T)]$?

My attempt is the martingale approach as follows:

Let $f(t,x)=\mathbb{E}[r_i(X_T)|X_t=x]$, then apply Ito lemma and set the drift to zero since $f(t,X_t)$ is a martingale we obtain the following PDE

\begin{equation}
f_t+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\sum_{k=1}^Nx_kf_{x_k}+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\sum_{k=1}^Nx_k^2f_{x_kx_k}=0
\end{equation}
with the terminal condition $f(T,x)=r_i(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}_+^N$. But solving this PDE is troublesome for me.

Comment: If you apply directly Ito's multidimensionnal formula to $F_i(B_t)= (x_i exp^{\sigma B^i_)}/\sum_1^N x_k exp^{\sigma B^k_t)} )$ you will get an SDE if you can prove that F(B) is a martingale then you will only to integrate over the drift that will only depend on $B$ (the stochastic integral term vanishes after taking expectation as it's a martingale), there won't be any pde then.

Comment: The calculation are tedious though ...

Comment: Thanks! I did some monte carlo simulation,  it appears to be a strict sub-martingale (supermartingale) if $r_i(x)<<1/N$ ($r_i(x)>>1/N$).

Comment: And the drift term is \begin{equation}  \sigma^2w_i\left(-w_i+\sum_{k=1}^Nw_k^2\right)\end{equation} where $w_k=r_k(x)$ for any $k\in\{1,...,N\}$.